# Who are Princess Celestia and Princess Luna's mother and father?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

**Who are Princess Celestia and Princess Luna's parents?**

[image]

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/8foqpi/my_little_pony_who_are_princess_celestialunas/

Comment: I'm voting to banish this question to the Moon for a thousand years as off-topic because it inquires into things into which one ought not inquire.

Answer (score 8):

Unknown and (as yet) unstated. Her parentage hasn't been revealed for fear that it would de-rank her.

> ***"I know "princess" sounds cuter and helps sell more toys, and because
> of that you were probably forced to keep her as a princess by the
> powers that be..."***
>
> *LF: That's what happened. I was told that because of Disney movies, girls
> assume that Queens are evil (although I only remember 1 evil queen)
> and Princesses are good. I was also told that the perceived youth of a
> Princess is preferable to consumers.*
>
> ***She does not have parents that outrank her. I brought the weirdness of
> that situation to my bosses, but it did not seem to be a continuity
> concern to them, so I'm letting it alone.** I always wanted her to be
> the highest authority, and so she remains so. And I certainly don't
> want marriage to be what would escalate her. (Bad messages to girls
> and what not.)*
>
> *Sorry I couldn't give you a more satisfying answer. Maybe as the
> series goes on we can thread something together. I put up a bit of a
> fight when her title changed, but you win some, you lose some.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fyre Flye (Lauren Faust)](https://comments.deviantart.com/4/1603670/1791456540)</sup></sub>